# InnoSetup making {app} dir for install.log

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I need to create an install.log of the selected components in the install destination folder ({app}) but I'm getting in issue when i run that installer that says "File does not exist C:/tmp/exe/install.log" I'm assuming that means it has not created the dir "exe" yet. How can i circumvent this?

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  I: Integer;
  LogList: TStringList;
begin
  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    LogList := TStringList.Create;
    try
      LogList.Add('Selected components:');
      for I := 0 to WizardForm.ComponentsList.Items.Count - 1 do
        if WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[I] then
          LogList.Add('Component: ' + WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemCaption[I]);

      LogList.SaveToFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\install.log'));
    finally
      LogList.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Why are you trying to `ExpandConstant` on something that isn't a constant? Try using `ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\install.log'` instead and see if that helps. (You may have to try it without the backslash; I don't remember if expanding a constant includes it or not.)

Comment: hmm that shouldn't be the problem. because i have done `ExpandConstant('{userdocs}\install.log')` before and it works fine. But probably it is better form to do it your way. But I don't think that solves the issue

Comment: You may indeed be trying to access the folder too early (before it's created). You might want to move it to a later step (after install, for instance), where you can be certain it's there.

Comment: Right, so your thinking `if CurStep = ssPostInstall then` ? I'll give that a shot

Comment: That would be my thought (couldn't remember the exact name of that step off-hand). :-)

Comment: Yep that worked! very simple fix! I was making it more complicated then it needed to be! thanks for the tip!

Comment: I've gone ahead and posted an answer, so that the information is available for future users who have a similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're trying to access the folder too early in the process, before it's actually been created yet.

Try changing to a later step in the process, such as `ssPostInstall`. At that point, you'll know for certain that the folder has been created. The rest of your code should be able to stay the same.

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  I: Integer;
  LogList: TStringList;
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    LogList := TStringList.Create;
    try
      LogList.Add('Selected components:');
      for I := 0 to WizardForm.ComponentsList.Items.Count - 1 do
        if WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[I] then
          LogList.Add('Component: ' + WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemCaption[I]);

      LogList.SaveToFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\install.log'));
    finally
      LogList.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```